# What were the most important discoveries of Galileo in mechanics?

Tags: physics, discoveries, classical-mechanics, galileo

Galileo was a real physicist and mathematician besides being an astronomer. But what were his contributions to mechanics like throw and fall and collision? Did he perhaps already know Newton's first law a little bit?

Comment: For an overview, see [Galileo's Physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Galilei#Physics).

Comment: For more details : Peter Damerow,Gideon Freudenthal,Peter McLaughlin,Jürgen Renn, [Exploring the Limits of Preclassical Mechanics: A Study of Conceptual Development in Early Modern Science: Free Fall and Compounded Motion in the Work of Descartes, Galileo and Beeckman](https://books.google.it/books?id=TYTdBwAAQBAJ&pg=PR13) (2004).

Comment: Also Winifred Wisan, [The New Science of Motion: A Study of Galileo’s *De Motu Locali*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/41133408.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (1974).

Answer (score 2):

His most important contribution was the Principle of Galilean Relativity. His second most important contribution was his [inclined plane experiment](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=eghdN-GFuqo) which showed all bodies accelerate at the same rate independent of their masses.